# Is there a way to explicitly ignore speicific API's warnings

Tags: valgrind

Related to my previous question:[Valgrind Memory check complains on TessBaseAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776333/valgrind-memory-check-complains-on-tessbaseapi) [newline]
Could not valgrind test my project for leaks, as valgrind complains for something, I could not understand and ammend.
And totally discarding all tessAPI calls from my project seem to be impossible.
I suppose there is a possibility to explicitly ignore specific (chosen) API warnings?
Please share any clues.

Comment: Maybe you are asking how to suppress some warnings from valgrind?  If so then you should read this: https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress

Comment: yes, trying all combinations, but can not get result
valgrind  --undef-value-errors=no --gen-suppressions=all  --vgdb-error=0 --leak-check=full -s ./MPU l use now

Comment: Don’t mix vgdb and suppression arguments. Just use one or the other.